# MySQL gives the error "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'PatientNum' at row 1"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting the following error when I submit a form into a MySQL database:

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'PatientNum' at row 1

The table structure in MySQL is

```
PatientNum    int(11)    No    None    AUTO_INCREMENT
```

In my form I am not puting any value for the `PatientNum`:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO patients (Title,etc......
```

Comment: it should be PatientNum int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: I think the `No` is in the `Null` column, so that's what he has.

Comment: Please show your actual code, not just a bit of it.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I have no experience in PHP but I can advise you on how to ask a good technical question.  Because your question lacks important information, we cannot give you any effective advices now.  Seems like PHP MySQL driver has a debugging output function.  Can you try this and copy&paste the result to your post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142087/displaying-errors-if-mysql-query-not-successful

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the value you put into the database is a valid integer.

See the PHP function is_numeric()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

it can also not be empty. So:

```
if (is_numeric($value) && ($value != '')) <put in database>
```